# Hide modeline in all bottom windows while helm is active?

Tags: helm, mode-line

I'm trying to hide the modeline whenever helm pops up. I have configure helm to always show up at the bottom.  It should look like this (two windows above the helm completion window):

[image]

Opposed of the regular way, where modelines from `*scratch*` and `test.el` buffer are shown like this:

[image]

I want to hide the modeline only in the bottom windows so if there are other windows above, their modeline should still be visible like this (three windows above the helm completion window):

[image]

I have written the following code to achieve this:

```el
(defun toggle-mode-line ()
  "toggles the visibility of modeline in bottom windows"
  (interactive)
  (dolist (current-window (window-list))
    (with-current-buffer (window-buffer current-window)
      (unless (window-in-direction 'below current-window)
        (setq mode-line-format 
              (unless mode-line-format
                (default-value 'mode-line-format)))))))
```

Now this has to be called before helm is activated to make the modeline invisible and after helm was activated it has to be called again to make it visible again. So far the following code works for hiding it:

```el
(add-hook 'helm-before-initialize-hook 'helm-toggle-mode-line)
```

But I couldn't find a way to make it visible again when the completion buffer is gone. This does not work:

```el
(add-hook 'helm-exit-minibuffer-hook 'toggle-mode-line)
```

And this does not work, too:

```el
(add-hook 'helm-cleanup-hook 'toggle-mode-line)
```

What's the proper way to achieve this?

EDIT:

The following works if I select a command in the helm completion buffer:

```el
(add-hook 'helm-before-action-hook 'toggle-mode-line)
```

But I still don't know how to make it visible again when I quit with `C-g` or calling `helm-keyboard-quit`. I tried this but it dosen't work:

```el
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-q") 'my-helm-keyboard-quit)

(defun my-helm-keyboard-quit ()
  (interactive)
  (helm-keyboard-quit)
  (message "this and the line below is not called for some reason")
  (toggle-mode-line))
```

Comment: Do you mean `helm-buffer` (that is, the completing buffer)  by saying "all bottom windows"? I ask this because the `helm-buffer` can be placed in anywhere by using different user configs, not just the bottom.

Comment: @xuchunyang I have added a picture to clarify.

Comment: @xuchunyang And another one. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: It's clear enough to me now.  How do you make the helm completion window always in the bottom? it isn't the default behavior of helm, for all I know, there is no user option for it.  In your `my-helm-keyboard-quit`, code after `helm-keyboard-quit` didn't work because it had been terminated in `helm-keyboard-quit`, it is like: you are unable to cleanup after you have killed your app.

Comment: @xuchunyang Thanks, I understand any idea how I could do it then? I tried advicing helm-keyboard-quit but it's the same problem. I use   [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle) for showing helm always at the bottom. This the shackle-rule I use:  `("\\`\\*helm.*?\\*\\'" :regexp t :align below :ratio 0.4)`

Comment: @xuchunyang I have a solution that kind of works when I use `run-with-timer` to call `(toggle-mode-line)` before `(helm-keyboard-quit)` but for some reason, I have to press a key before the mode line shows up again after I quit.

Comment: The simplest way is re-defining `helm-keyboard-quit` by inserting your own code (that is, `(toggle-mode-line)`) at the beginning of it (and after `(interactive)`, of course) then `C-M-x`.

Comment: @xuchunyang Thanks, it still does not work, only when I replace `(abort-recursive-edit)` in `helm-keyboard-quit` with `(helm-exit-minibuffer)` and toggle the mode line after this. But then it dosen't work as expected in helm find files etc. where it suddenly executes action instead of quitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```lisp
;; 1. Collect bottom buffers
(defvar bottom-buffers nil
  "List of bottom buffers before helm session.
    Its element is a pair of `buffer-name' and `mode-line-format'.")

(defun bottom-buffers-init ()
  (when bottom-buffers
    (bottom-buffers-show-mode-line))
  (setq bottom-buffers
        (cl-loop for w in (window-list)
                 when (window-at-side-p w 'bottom)
                 collect (with-current-buffer (window-buffer w)
                           (cons (buffer-name) mode-line-format)))))

(add-hook 'helm-before-initialize-hook #'bottom-buffers-init)

;; 2. Hide mode line
(defun bottom-buffers-hide-mode-line ()
  (mapc (lambda (elt)
          (with-current-buffer (car elt)
            (setq-local mode-line-format nil)))
        bottom-buffers))

(add-hook 'helm-after-initialize-hook #'bottom-buffers-hide-mode-line)

;; 3. Restore mode line
(defun bottom-buffers-show-mode-line ()
  (when bottom-buffers
    (mapc (lambda (elt)
            (with-current-buffer (car elt)
              (setq-local mode-line-format (cdr elt))))
          bottom-buffers)
    (setq bottom-buffers nil)))

(add-hook 'helm-exit-minibuffer-hook #'bottom-buffers-show-mode-line)

(defun helm-keyboard-quit-advice (orig-func &rest args)
  (bottom-buffers-show-mode-line)
  (apply orig-func args))

(advice-add 'helm-keyboard-quit :around #'helm-keyboard-quit-advice)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The display has to be updated after the mode-line modification with `(redraw-display)`:

```el
(defun toggle-mode-line ()
      "toggles the visibility of modeline in bottom windows"
      (interactive)
      (dolist (current-window (window-list))
        (with-current-buffer (window-buffer current-window)
          (unless (window-in-direction 'below current-window)
            (setq mode-line-format
                  (unless mode-line-format
                    (default-value 'mode-line-format))))))
      (redraw-display))
```

As @xuchunyang has noted `my-helm-keyboard-quit` does not work because everything is stopped before `toggle-mode-line` is executed. To make it work after quitting helm I used the following:

```el
(defun helm-keyboard-quit-advice (orig-func &rest args)
  (interactive)
  (run-with-timer .03 nil 'toggle-mode-line)
  (apply orig-func args))


(advice-add 'helm-keyboard-quit :around #'helm-keyboard-quit-advice)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to hide helm's informative mode line, try this:

```lisp
;;; Don't use helm's own displaying mode line function
(fset 'helm-display-mode-line #'ignore)

(add-hook 'helm-after-initialize-hook
          (defun hide-mode-line-in-helm-buffer ()
            "Hide mode line in `helm-buffer'."
            (with-helm-buffer
              (setq-local mode-line-format nil))))
```

BTW, you might also want to hide minibuffer content when turning on `helm-echo-input-in-header-line`:

```lisp
(setq helm-echo-input-in-header-line t)
;;; Hide minibuffer contents when the above option is on.
(add-hook 'helm-minibuffer-set-up-hook
          #'helm-hide-minibuffer-maybe)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but you have misunderstood my question. I want to hide the modeline of the buffers above the helm completion buffer (like shown in the picture).  I already have achieved this with my code but have still dificulties showing them  again when the helm completion buffer is gone.

Comment: I already have the `helm-echo-input-in-header-line` set to true. Please take a look at the new pictures, I have added to the question.